# String to dictionary and backwards

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, dictionary, time

I've designed a solution for ESTIMOTE Beacons, which doesnt annoy you everytime you pass by the region, but I'm new to Objective C, iOS, iPhones etc. and I cant really got things work in Objective-C. We assume here that we have only one beacon in region. So everytime you enter a region it starts to range, finds the only 1 beacon and does following:
checks if a specific file is on a specific path, if not it creates the file and puts a string into it like "major_as_int:actual_time;", sends major value to .php file via get variable and php does the job.
Here is my first question. How to get time in format "23:10:01"?
If file is already there checks if its empty, IF FILE ISNT EMPTY here comes my second question....
How can I convert a string into a dictionary, edit dictionary, and then convert dictionary back to string so that I can replace old string in the file with new string that came out of dictionary?
For example: I have already a string in my file "12345:12:45:12;54321:20:15:01;90900:05:21:13;" and I'd like to make dictionary out of it { 12345 : 12:45:12, 54321 : 20:15:01, 90900 : 05:21:13 }. Major values should be integers in the dictionary, so that I can ask is the actual major value in the dictionary as a key. If it is, check how long its been there, if 24 hours or more are over, do php again. if not, just do nothing. return same string to file. If actual major value is not in the dictionary, add actual major value as new key with value of actual time. Dictionary would look like { 12345 : 12:45:12, 54321 : 20:15:01, 90900 : 05:21:13, 88771 : 10:12:33 }. Then dictionary gets converted back to a string "12345:12:45:12;54321:20:15:01;90900:05:21:13;88771:10:12:33;"
Some snippets of code would be nice to see but im willing to learn cuz its my future job, so please show me right direction and dont post too much code. Or maybe im attacking problem in the wrong way? thanks in advance.

Comment: Do u have the liberty of changing the delimiter from ":" to some other character in you string. For Example: "12345#12:45:12" ?

Comment: yes it was just as example

Answer (score 2):

That should do the conversion of the string into a dictionary (haven't tested it though). The backward conversion should be clear from this example.

```
    NSString *string1 = @"12345:12:45:12;54321:20:15:01;90900:05:21:13;";
    NSArray *components1 = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *string2 in components1) {
        NSArray *components2 = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        NSMutableArray *mutableComponents2 = [components2 mutableCopy];
        NSString *majorValue = [mutableComponents2 firstObject];

        // Check whether there is actually a majorValue
        if (majorValue) {
            [mutableComponents2 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            mutableDictionary[majorValue] = [mutableComponents2 componentsJoinedByString:@":"];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"mutableDictionary: %@", mutableDictionary);
```

Edit: In case your string looks like `123#12:12:12;` this would change to

```
    NSString *string1 = @"12345#12:45:12;54321#20:15:01;90900#05:21:13;";
    NSArray *components1 = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *string2 in components1) {
        NSArray *components2 = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
        NSMutableArray *mutableComponents2 = [components2 mutableCopy];
        NSString *majorValue = [mutableComponents2 firstObject];

        // Check whether there is actually a majorValue
        if (majorValue) {
            mutableDictionary[majorValue] = [mutableComponents2 lastObject];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"mutableDictionary: %@", mutableDictionary);
```

Comment: how would look like second statement in the if, if my string would look like "123#12:12:12;" ? And about NSArray *compenents1. What happens with last ";" ? Does components1 has an empty string as last object in array?

Comment: @onskulis See my changes.

Comment: what about last semi column in the string?

Comment: This is taken care of by `if (majorValue) {`. Try it, add break points.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, on how to get time on the format 23:59:59, I present the following code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@implementation NSDateFormatter(myCategory)
+ (NSDateFormatter *)for24Hours {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *template = [[self class] dateFormatTemplateFor24Hours];
    [formatter setDateFormat:template];
    return formatter;
}
+ (NSString *)dateFormatTemplateFor24Hours {
    NSString  *template = @"HHmmss";
    const NSUInteger options = 0;
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *dateAs24Hours = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:template options:options locale:locale];
    return dateAs24Hours;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter for24Hours];
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:now]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted the snippet without main function into my ViewController.m it works great thanks, buw I've added a method to NSDateFormater(myCategory) and called it "getDate" which returns what NSLog in your example returns. How can I call my method? I've tryed many variatons but nothing works.

Comment: Try `[NSDateFormatter getDate];` , I recomment that you read about Categories, if you are unfamiliar with the concept, Apple has nice documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html